# Populating a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to store a word count for each word in multiple files. In Perl I used a hash of a hash such as `$wcCount{$file}{$word}`. I can't figure out how to do a similar thing in python. I tried using something of this effect but it clearly didn't work

```
for line in fh:
    arr = line.split()
    for word in arr:
        key = filename + word  #creates a unique identifier for each word count
        freqdict[key] += 1
```

I read the other stackoverflow for a similar question, however it doesn't allow to update the value as the word is counted again.

The input is multiple files fulls of words. The the output should just be a list of frequencies for a word (which is put as a command line argument) for each file.

Comment: Could you provide example input and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have [Hamlet](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7p3uycAz) and you want to count the unique words.

You can do:

```
# the tools we need, read a url and regex library 
import urllib2
import re

# a dict -- similar to Perl hash
words={}

# read the text at that url
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7p3uycAz')
hamlet = response.read()

# split on whitespace, remove trailing punctuation, and count each unique word
for word in hamlet.split():
    word=re.sub(r'\W+$', r'', word)
    if word.strip(): 
        words[word]=words.setdefault(word, 0) +1
```

Then if you want to print the words sorted from most common to least:

```
# sort descending on count, ascending on ascii lower case
for word, count in sorted(words.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0].lower())):
    print word, count
```

Prints:

```
the 988
and 702
of 628
to 610
I 541
you 495
a 452
my 441
in 399
HAMLET 385
it 360
is 313
...
```

If you want a nested Dict of Dicts (as your Perl example suggests) you might do something like this:

```
# think of these strings like files; the letters like words
str1='abcdefaaa'
str2='abefdd'
str3='defeee'

letters={}

for fn, st in (('string 1', str1), ('string 2', str2) , ('string 3', str3)):
    letters[fn]={}
    for c in st:
        letters[fn][c]=letters[fn].setdefault(c, 0)
        letters[fn][c]+=1

print letters     
# {'string 3': {'e': 4, 'd': 1, 'f': 1}, 
   'string 1': {'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1}, 
   'string 2': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'f': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with using a `Counter` and utilising a tuple (filename, word) as a key value, eg:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

word_counts = Counter()
for filename in ['your', 'file names', 'here']:
    with open(filename) as fin:
        words = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in fin)
        word_counts.update((filename, word) for word in words)
```

However, what you could also do, is create an initial dictionary based on the filenames, with a `Counter`, then update that so you have access to a "hash" as it were with the filename as a key, then the word count, eg:

```
word_counts = {filename: Counter() for filename in your_filenames}
for filename, counter in word_counts.items():
    with open(filename) as fin:
        words = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in fin)
        word_counts[filename].update(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest collections.Counter, if you're in Python 2.7 or later:

```
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()

for line in fh:
    arr = line.split()
    for word in arr:
        key = filename + word  #creates a unique identifier for each word count
        counter.update((key,))
```

You can view the counts like this:

```
for key, value in counter.items():
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: why would you concatenate the filename and the word instead of using a dict of counters, with the filenames as the dict keys?

Comment: Because that's not the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Perl programmer, but I believe the following solution in Python would get you the closest to `$wcCount{$file}{$word}` in Perl.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def count_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        word_iter = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f)
        return Counter(word_iter)

word_counts = {file_name : count_words(file_name) for file_name in file_names}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you may benefit from learning about [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) (Natural Language Toolkit).
If you end up doing more than just word frequency it may be a big help.

Here it parses out sentences and then words:

```
import nltk
import urllib2

hamlet = urllib2.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7p3uycAz').read().lower()

word_freq = nltk.FreqDist()
for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(hamlet):
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence): 
        word_freq[word] += 1
```

word_freq:

> > FreqDist({',': 3269, '.': 1283, 'the': 1138, 'and': 965, 'to': 737, 'of': 669, 'i': 629, ';': 582, 'you': 553, ':': 535, ...})